# Java JLabel won't update

Tags: java, swing

Edited Version, I hope this is what are you looking for. I tried to keep only necesery things in this version. I don't know what else to write, but i can't upload this edit becouse code is to big and text so small, so i write random stuf..

mainClass :

```
package Clicker;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class mainClass {

     public static void main(String[] args) {


         ClickerGame CG = new ClickerGame();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("CarCollectionarV1");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            CG.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setResizable(true);
            frame.setSize(1000, 700);

     }
}
```

ClickerGame Class :

```
package Clicker;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ClickerGame implements ActionListener {

       JButton jbtnMoney = new JButton("Click");
       JButton jbtnBoxes = new JButton("Click");

       final static String Click = "Click";

       //Make TabbedPane
        public void addComponentToPane(Container pane){

            jbtnMoney.addActionListener(this);
            jbtnBoxes.addActionListener(this);

        LabelsHolder Labels = new LabelsHolder(); // Imports JLabels

        //Visual        
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.TOP);

        //MainPanel
        JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();

        JPanel MainPanelSub = new JPanel();
        MainPanelSub.setLayout(new BoxLayout(MainPanelSub, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JPanel MainPanelSub2 = new JPanel();
        MainPanelSub2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(MainPanelSub2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


        MainPanelSub.add(Labels.MoneyLabel);
        MainPanelSub.add(Labels.MoneyClicksLabel);
        MainPanelSub.add(jbtnMoney);
        MainPanelSub2.add(Labels.BoxesLabel);
        MainPanelSub2.add(Labels.BoxesClicksLabel);
        MainPanelSub2.add(jbtnBoxes);
        MainPanel.add(MainPanelSub);

        tabbedPane.addTab(Click, MainPanel);
        pane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        }

        MainHolder CarMain = new MainHolder();
        LabelsHolder Labels = new LabelsHolder();
         //Button Click

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        //Money Button Click
        if(ae.getSource() == jbtnMoney) {           
            CarMain.main[0] += 1;   
            CarMain.main[1] += 1;
            Labels.MoneyLabel.setText("Test");
        }
        }
}
```

LabelsHolder class :

```
package Clicker;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

class LabelsHolder {

    MainHolder CarMain = new MainHolder();


    public JLabel MoneyLabel = new JLabel();  
    public JLabel MoneyClicksLabel = new JLabel();
    public JLabel BoxesLabel = new JLabel();
    public JLabel BoxesClicksLabel = new JLabel();

    public LabelsHolder(){

        MoneyLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        MoneyLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        MoneyLabel.setText("Money: " + CarMain.main[0]);

        MoneyClicksLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        MoneyClicksLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        MoneyClicksLabel.setText("Money Clicks: " + CarMain.main[1]);

        BoxesLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        BoxesLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        BoxesLabel.setText("Boxes: " + CarMain.main[2]);

        BoxesClicksLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        BoxesClicksLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        BoxesClicksLabel.setText("Boxes Clicks: " + CarMain.main[3]);

    }
}
```

MainHolder Class :

```
package Clicker;

public class MainHolder {

public Integer main[] = new Integer[4];

    public MainHolder(){

        MakeMain();     
    }

    public void MainMaker(int k,int p){

        main[p] = k;

    }

    public void MakeMain(){



        int i=0;
        MainMaker(0,i); // Money
        i++;
        MainMaker(0,i); // Money Clicks
        i++;
        MainMaker(0,i); // Boxes
        i++;
        MainMaker(0,i); // Boxes Clicks
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Labels`? How do these classes interact? Please create and post a valid [mcve] so we can better understand your code and your problem (please read the link).

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Also, there is no need to call `repaint()` after setting a JLabel's text. My guess is that you're setting the text of a JLabel that is not being visualized, but I can't prove this guess based on what you've posted so far. Also, I see that you've edited your question since my comments above, but haven't really improved it enough to be answerable just yet. Please help us help you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tried, to edit code, hope you will now understand.

Comment: Thanks for the update -- and I know this sounds selfish, but I want to see more,... .and less. Please try to create a new program, a small program, but one that we can copy, paste into our IDE, and actually run unaltered, and that shows the problem for us, a valid [mcve] (again, please read the link). This would be posted here as code with your question, like the code you've posted above, and not posted in a link. If you can post this and do it right, I can almost guarantee you a prompt answer.

Comment: ... and by "less" I mean removing code and components not relevant to your problem. Your simple [mcve] program should perhaps have a single JLabel and a single button, and again should run and reproduce your problem, but not have code for anything else.

Comment: ..... Hello?? One thing you can do on your own is to search through your files and see how many times you've created a new LabelsHolder instance. Specifically, look for how many times `new LabelsHolder();` appears in your program. It should only appear ***once***.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I updated version for you. And now will try to find all these Holders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating two LabelsHolder instances:

```
class ClickerGame implements ActionListener {

        // ....
        LabelsHolder Labels = new LabelsHolder(); // **** here

        // Visual
        // .....
    }

    // and here!!!@
    MainHolder CarMain = new MainHolder();
    LabelsHolder Labels = new LabelsHolder();
```

Doing this means that your ActionListener is changing the state of a non-visualized JLabel. The solution: Create and use only one. So get rid of the instance declared inside of the constructor and instead only use the instance field.

Other suggestions:

- You will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.
- You should avoid using public fields and allowing other classes direct access to these fields. Much better would be to use private fields and public methods that limit the exposure of your object states.